# While performing the REST API automation using HTPP CLIENT or REST ASSURED , how to validate the response with Database

Tags: java, rest, api, automation, apache-httpclient-4.x

When we automate the REST APIs using HTTP CLIENT / REST ASSURED libraries, we get the response object. How to validate the response object with source of truth as Database ?

Even though we will establish the Database connection object using JDBC, validating the response by fetching the resultset from DAO is not a best practice. Please suggest.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use the database as the source of truth here?  What would be wrong with just asserting some hard coded values?

Comment: Everytime the new record created by the post call, should be validated in DB.